# Preprocessor directives in C#

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

In C#, if preprocessor directives are instructions pre-processed before actual compilation then why is it not executed first in this program?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program1.display();
            Program2 p2 = new Program2();
            p2.show();
#if DEBUG
Console.WriteLine("DEBUG from preprocessor directive is working!");
#endif
        }
```

Expected Output:

```
DEBUG from preprocessor directive is working!
.......(from display())
.......(from show())
```

But Actual Output:

```
.......(from display())
.......(from show())
DEBUG from preprocessor directive is working!
```

Comment: But code will run line by line

Comment: Preprocessor directives are *instructions to the compiler* about how to compile the program. They do not have any bearing on code execution order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output you are expecting is wrong.

Code processed (to be compiled) in `DEBUG` mode/configuration

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program1.display();
    Program2 p2 = new Program2();
    p2.show();
    Console.WriteLine("DEBUG from preprocessor directive is working!");
}
```

Code processed (to be compiled) in **non**-`DEBUG` mode/configuration

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program1.display();
    Program2 p2 = new Program2();
    p2.show();
}
```

Hope this clears your confusion that preprocessors don't decide execution order.

Answer (score 3):

C# Language Specification, Section2.5

> The pre-processing directives provide the ability to conditionally
>   skip sections of source files, to report error and warning conditions,
>   and to delineate distinct regions of source code. The term
>   “pre-processing directives” is used only for consistency with the C
>   and C++ programming languages. In C#, there is no separate
>   pre-processing step; pre-processing directives are processed as part
>   of the lexical analysis phase

---

> Pre-processing directives are not tokens and are not part of the
>   syntactic grammar of C#. However, pre-processing directives can be
>   used to include or exclude sequences of tokens and can in that way
>   affect the meaning of a C# program